# Envrionmental Variables in info.plist don't work

Tags: xcode, environment-variables, info.plist, dyld

I am using an info.plist in Xcode to set the Environmental Variables, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH.

I am setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to

$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/runtime/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tiapp/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/ticodec/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tidatabase/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tifilesystem/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/timedia/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/timonkey/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tinetwork/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tiplatform/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tiprocess/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tiui/1.1.0:$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/modules/tiworker/1.1.0

and

DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH to

$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/runtime/1.1.0

And when I double click my .app folder dlopen can't find any of my .dylib that are referenced in the folders above.

If I take the same exact variables and paths and place them in my Executable Arguments in Xcode, everything works fine, but only if I run the software through Xcode, and I need everything to work when you click on the .app folder.

What am I doing wrong in the info.plist?  Does it not like the $CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH?  Does it need a different delimiter?  Why does the same arguments work in the Executable Arguments but not in the info.plist file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the @rpath to find all my dylibs and frameworks.  I rebuilt all frameworks and libraries with the install name of @rpath/-name of library or framework-.

Then I added in the main project's run search path settings relative path names like @loader_path/../runtime/1.1.0 and @loader_path/../modules/, etc...

This allows dlopen call to find the current path without using plist or executable arguments.

Answer (score 2):

What key are you using in `Info.plist` to set environment variables? Do you mean you're setting environment variables in Xcode's "Environment Variables" configuration (part of the Scheme in Xcode 4, part of the Custom Executable in Xcode 3), or do you mean you're just throwing key/values into `Info.plist` and expecting them to show up in the environment?

In the former case, even if this worked, it would only be useful while you were running Xcode, not when you shipped your product. In the latter case, `Info.plist` doesn't have a mechanism for adding environment variables to my knowledge.

Personally, rather than having this huge tree in your bundle, I'd have Xcode copy all of your dylibs into your bundle's plugin directory (`PlugIns`) and then use `NSBundle` (or `CFBundle`) to get the path to it. Or you could use another directory if these aren't really "plugins." But put them all in one directory inside your bundle. Don't search for them. (You are free to have them in many directories in your source tree; this is purely about the bundle.)

Comment: I am using Xcode 3, and I am setting the info.plist variable "Environment Variables", in the actually info.plist it shows up as LSEnvironment.  I can find my direct path to each of my .dylib's in my bundle, but the problem is that the .dylibs themselves depend on other .dylibs so when I make the dlopen call and the loading .dylib uses the environmental variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to find the paths to the other .dylibs that it depends on, so I need to append paths from my bundle to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable before the app opens up.  I need this to work where ever the app may be too.

Comment: Xcode build variables like CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH aren't available at runtime to Launch Services. I would start by pursuing a simpler linking system, ideally a static linking system. Otherwise, you're going to need to either set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in your code, and if even that's impossible, you'll need to build a helper executable that sets it for you, based on your bundle's location, and then launches your real executable. All of these are excessively complex approaches, and static linking is strongly preferred.

Comment: I don't think static linking is an option for me right now.  Thanks though for the suggestions.  In fact the current design was to have the first run of the application set the environmental variables and then launch the same executable again which then will have the environmental variables set, kinda like your build helper suggestion.  I am trying to avoid this approach and hopefully have a single execution of the app, to make things easier on everyone.